# Cannot Update. Database or Object is Read-only after Requery

Tags: ms-access, vba

Okay, cannot find anything online about this error, so here goes.

Using Access 2003.  I have a form that has a combobox dropdown.  Users choose from the dropdown, and the VBA code looks at a particular table to see if data already exists.  If it finds it, it displays the data associated with the record.  If it does not find it, it adds a new record to the table, then tries to display the new data.  The problem is that when using the following code, it does not display the new data, unless I add in Me.Requery.  However, if I do that, it then gives me the above error if I try to do the same process again.

So, how can I get the data to display after adding without the above error?

Here is the relevant code...

```
' Find the record that matches the control.
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone

'if no record found, then add a default record
If IsNull(Combo119) Then
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Master Reject Data]")
    rs.AddNew
    rs.Fields("production Date") = Date
    rs.Fields("Work Order #") = Combo119.Column(0)
    rs.Fields("Product Type") = ""
    rs.Fields("Shift") = ""
    rs.Fields("Line") = ""
    rs.Fields("# Produced") = 0
    rs.Fields("Reject Type") = ""
    rs.Fields("Reject Quantity") = 0
    rs.Fields("Reject Category") = "Rejection"
    Dim tRec As Long
    tRec = Combo142.ItemData(0)
    rs.Fields("Report Number") = tRec
    rs.Update
    Me.Requery 'this is the line I added to try to get the data to appear
    Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
    rs.FindFirst "[Report Number] = " & tRec 'navigate to the newly added record
Else
    rs.FindFirst "[Report Number] = " & Nz(Me![Combo119], 0) 'navigate to the record with the requested report number
End If
If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, found the issue after looking at it again.  The problem is that the Me.Requery statement needs to be Me.Recordset.Requery.  After doing that and adding Me.Refresh, it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid requerying I think you should open the recordset specifying that it should be a dynaset
`CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Master Reject Data]", dbOpenDynaset)` - in case you want to make it a bit neater. as for the small bug, I see you've already found yourself